# Iterate through a loop to print arraylist with 1sec delay in a textview Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, textview

I am trying to print the elements of an ArrayList one at the time with a delay in the same TextView, no matter what I try, when executed there is a delay, but the only element printed is the last of the array. Just to extend on the context, the method "iniciate" is executed on an onClick of a button, then a random number is added to the ArrayList and the elements are printed on the textview one at the time with a delay (that´s what I am trying to achieve), the every time the method is executed it adds an extra element to the ArrayList and print it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText et1;
private TextView tv2;
private ArrayList<String> numbers=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1=findViewById(R.id.et1);
        tv2=findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    }

    public void iniciate(View view){
        numbers.add(String.valueOf ((int) (Math.random() * 10)+1));

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            tv2.setText(numbers.get(i));

            tv2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv2.setText("");
                }
            },2000);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading the code, I can see that there's only one element in the array, so your function printing only one element makes sense. This is because you're only adding to the array once, a random number times 10 plus 1, casted to String.

```
numbers.add(String.valueOf ((int) (Math.random() * 10)+1));
```

I checked using an online java compiler. [The test is here.](https://paiza.io/projects/PIhMSeZRoXp4WoeZWtkB3Q)

That being said, my guess is that you're dinamically adding elements to the array using that code (Using events, perhaps?). If so, please update your question adding that, since as it is, it seems you just need to add a little loop surrounding the add() method of `numbers`, like:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
    numbers.add(String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 10)+1));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: The method "iniciate" is assigned to an onClick for a button, any time the button is pressed one random number is added to the ArrayList, and at the same time the elements of the ArrayList are printed one by one (or that´s is what I am trying to achieve) with a delay in a textview, also to clarify this is in Android Studio, the next time the button is pressed, an extra number is added to the ArrayList and prited again.